# iOS CLRegion monitoring stops working after a day

Tags: ibeacon, clregion

I have set up an app to monitor for both geofence (CLCircularRegion) and iBeacon (CLBeaconRegion) monitoring for entry / exit events.  Everything works fine for about a day in both foreground and background.  I get entry / exit events (generate a UNNotificationRequest to show a local notification) just as I would expect. I can run multiple other apps that would presumably force my app out of memory, and I still get entry / exit events that launch the handler which generates the notification. But a day later I stop getting the events, or at least stop getting the notifications.  I'm running iOS 13 on an iPhone Xs. Any insights into what might be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I resolved the issue.  My CLLocationManager delegate was being set in a ViewController.  I discovered watching the console on the device that the region (beacon) was being detected and my app was going to be called, but the delegate was nil.  So, I moved setting the CLLocationManager delegate to didFinishLaunching in my AppDelegate, and now everything's working.  It makes sense that didFinishLaunching gets called by iOS before calling the delegate method.

Comment: Hi there, I was wondering whether you could provide some code snippets that show your approach. I'm trying to achieve the same use case, but struggling to get it resolved. You have obviously succeeded in that :)